# How do I acknowledge / requeue with cloud stream sqs binders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am writing an application to consume messages from queue. I am able to successfully bind the sqs and receive the messages. However, when I want to requeue the message, I am using as follows.

```
message.getHeaders().get(AwsHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, QueueMessageAcknowledgment.class)
                    .acknowledge();
```

I also use to requeue

```
StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getAcknowledgmentCallback(message).acknowledge(AcknowledgmentCallback.Status.REQUEUE);
```

But it is not successful.

I also tried PollableMessage but unclear of how to implement it.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_overview_2

I've a Consumer like this

```
public class DefaultChannel implements Channel, Consumer<Message<String>> {

@Override
    public void accept(Message<String> message) {
if("success".equals(message.getPayLoad()){
message.getHeaders().get(AwsHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, QueueMessageAcknowledgment.class)
                    .acknowledge();
}else{
StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getAcknowledgmentCallback(message).acknowledge(AcknowledgmentCallback.Status.REQUEUE);
}

}

}
```

Comment: What binder are you using? That functionality is specific to both binder as well as capabilities of the underlying system. It is not something generic

Comment: https://github.com/idealo/spring-cloud-stream-binder-sqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to re-queue succesfully `messageDeletionPolicy: ON_SUCCESS` properties and throwing Exception from the code.